# Neo4j / Cypher - How to associate an optional match with path when getting hierarchical data and converting to tree?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm not sure if that title makes complete sense, but here is what I'm trying to do.

I have the following query that works fine:

```
MATCH (n:Thing)-[:has_child*0..]->(m) 
WHERE NOT ()-[:has_child]->(n)
WITH n, m 
ORDER BY n.name, m.name 
MATCH p=(n:Thing)-[:has_child*0..]->(m) 
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps 
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value 
RETURN value
```

I also have the following query that is also fine which is executed in another part of the application (because I can't figure out how to to it at once):

```
MATCH (n:Thing {name: {nameParam}})<-[:has_child*]-(m:Thing 
      {btogstate: {btogstateParam}})
RETURN m
```

So what is happening in the second query is that it is looking up the chain to see if btogstate is set to a certain value. What I'd like to do is combine the two.

Does anyone know how I could put the second query into the first one so that when accessing the tree (value) that I would know that that record has or does not have the value I was querying for?

Hopefully that makes sense. I know this is probably not a common issue.

**Update to clarify question**

Let's say we have some hierarchical data that looks like this, and in the DB it looks like (pseudo) (asdf)-[:has_child]->(qwer)-[:has_child]-> and so on:

```
--asdf
   -qwer
     -wert
       -erty
--rtyu
   -yuio
```

Now let's say that we need to know if 'erty' has anything up it's relational chain that has the property of btogstate set to false, and let's say that qwer does in fact have this property set to false.

Then the question is: how can the query be structured in a way that when you read the results (value) you know that 'erty' had a parent that had btogstate set to false?

Comment: Hello. I'm not 100% sure what you want to do. First off, you seem to be doing the same thing twice in the first query. Is the reason for that the ordering ? If so, the match for the second part can simply be reduced to MATCH p=(n)-[:has_child*0..]->(m). You don't need the where, the filter has already happened in the first part. Secondly you want to filter on the btogstate property. Would a simple extra WHERE-clause in the first part be sufficient (on n.btogstate or m.btogstate not sure which since you seem to reverse the order of the relationship) ?

Comment: @TomGeudens yes, it was for ordering, and so I've removed the second where. Thank you (I'm still quite new to Cypher so still figuring out how stuff works). As for the second question, I've updated my question to clarify what it is I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching something like that :

```
MATCH p=(n:Thing)-[:has_child*0..]->(m) 
WHERE NOT ()-[:has_child]->(n) AND
      any(node IN NODES(p) WHERE node.btogstate = $btogstateParam )
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps 
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value 
RETURN value
```

Like Tom said, I have done a refactoring on the first part of your query (combine the path and the where clause).

And to combine your 2 queries, I have used the `any`  function.

Cheers.

Comment: (I've updated my question to clarify) this doesn't work as it will only return nodes that meet the parameter. I need all of the nodes but then also need to know if anything up that particular node's tree meets the parameter, and I need to know it specifically in the returned value at the end, otherwise I don't know how you would know that a specific node met that condition or not in the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually looking for - I think - is setting a temporary property that will only show-up in your result. Now, you could actually do that (outside Neo4j) when processing the tree after doing the query. If you want to do it in Neo4j itself the way I would do it is with three queries :

```
MATCH (m:Thing)<-[:HAS_CHILD*0..]-(n:Thing {btogstate: "true"})
WHERE m <> n
SET m.hasit = "yes";

MATCH (n:Thing)-[:HAS_CHILD*0..]->(m) 
WHERE NOT ()-[:HAS_CHILD]->(n)
WITH n, m 
ORDER BY n.name, m.name
MATCH p=(n)-[:HAS_CHILD*0..]->(m)
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value 
RETURN value;

MATCH (m:Thing)
REMOVE m.hasit;
```

A Cypher expert (please chime in :-) can probably do this in one statement. I think that would however not improve the readability.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom, I tried this out and it does indeed work, but still looking for a single statement so that everything executes or it doesn't (without having to employ a bunch of rollback stuff, which I'm just assuming would be the case as I'm still too new to know). As a work around I've done like you said and after the return I'm using some flag setting/reseting in my reducer that handles the returned tree.

Comment: Understood. I've tried that first as well. The issue is that the resultset of your main query (the tree) is broader than the resultset that complies with the condition (basically what you are stating in the response given by logisima). A given Cypher statement - as far as I understand - will only work on/with one resultset. But I'll search a bit further ...